# How send a bitmap in SMS?

Tags: android, bitmap, sms, screenshot

I have tried to send a text to a phone number by using below code. Now I want to send a screenshot of the screen to the mobile number on button click.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button send;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
send= (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            smssend("03006110857","hi");
        }
    });




}
public void smssend(String phoneno,String msg){
try {
    SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneno,null,msg,null,null);
    Toast.makeText(this, "msg send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (Exception e)
{

    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to send that as a MMS (multimedia message)? What resources in the manual have you tried to fulfil this requirement?

Comment: yes i want to send it as mms

Comment: i have nothing tried rifgt now

Comment: because i have not idea how to do it. i m pretty noob in android

Comment: I don't develop for Android, but I should think this is covered in the manual. Being a beginner at something does not mean you should skip checking the manual. Have you found the right page in the manual? Is an example available there?

Comment: There are a [good number of questions here tagged Android and MMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mms%20android?mode=all), are any of these any good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this library will help you.

https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms